# Is it possible to divide the real line into two disjoint totally disconnected spaces of equal cardinality?

Tags: descriptive-set-theory

Is it explicitly possible to take $ \mathbb R$ and to divide it into two sets (say $\mathbb A$ and $\mathbb B$), which are : disjoint ($\mathbb A \cap \mathbb B = \emptyset$), totally disconnected (i.e. contain no open intervals) (EDIT:) and for all intervals $(a,b)$, $|\mathbb A \cap (a,b)| = |\mathbb B \cap (a,b)| = \mathfrak c$

I asked my measure theory professor, and he said he couldn't think of why such a construction would be impossible, but whenever I try to create such two sets I always end up with undefinable points, nor did an internet search reveal anything about this.

Comment: For an example that satisfies the added "local measure" condition, perhaps the union of all the rational translates of the Cantor set (and the complement of that union) does the trick?

Comment: ... or, a simpler representation of @Travis's idea: let $A$ be the set of numbers whose decimal representation eventually consists only of the digits $2$ and $7$.

Comment: @Henning-Makholm Thats the Smith-Volterra-Cantor set, its compliment contains intervals

Comment: @EdvinOrlov: No it isn't. My $A$ contains numbers in every interval -- note that its elements can have a finite number of digits that are _not_ $2$ or $7$. In particular, $A$ contains every number of the form $\frac n{10^m}+\frac29$; those are a dense set.

Comment: @Henning-Makholm my bad. I think that is the solution to the question, thank you!

Comment: Just to make it seem more psychologically equal, I'll go with $A$ is the set of all reals, whose decimal representation contains only $0,2,4,6,8 $ :D

Comment: @EdvinOrlov That's not right - it's the set of reals whose decimal representations *eventually consist* only of ---s. E.g. in Henning's example, $0.123452727272727272727272727...$ would be in the set, even though it has a few non-$2$-or-$7$ digits. The set you've defined has a complement containing lots of intervals.

Comment: @Noah-Schweber if $(a,b)$ is such an interval in $A^{c}$, there exists a rational $r$ with a finite decimal expansion in the interval ( $ a < r < b $). Since $A$ was the set of numbers whose representation contains only  numbers from the set $\{0,2,4,6,8\}$, the complement contains numbers whose repre. is from $\{1,3,5,7,9\}$. Trivially there exists a natural number $m$ such that $2 \times 10^{-m} + r $ is in the interval, yet such a number is not in $A^{c}$, hence $(a,b)$ is not an interval in $A^{c}$

Comment: @EdvinOrlov "Since $A$ was the set of numbers whose representation contains only numbers from the set $\{0,2,4,6,8\}$, the complement contains numbers whose representation is from $\{1,3,5,7,9\}$." **That's incorrect**. For example, the number $0.11222222...$ has a "$1$" in it, so is not in $A$ - if you're not in $A$, you're in the complement of $A$! In particular, every number in the interval $(0.11, 0.12)$ has a $1$ in its decimal expansion, so is not in $A$ - so that whole interval is in the complement of $A$. In fact, $A$ is [nowhere dense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_dense_set).

Comment: That's why the word "eventually" is crucial in Henning's answer - that way, given any finite decimal sequence (say, $113125$) we can find a number that begins with that sequence but is still in the set (say, $0.113125222222222...$), in particular implying that $A$ is dense. Do you see why this is important, now?

Comment: Yes, I see now. Thanks for taking the time to point that out!

Comment: In your revised question, "totally disconnected" is redundant.

Comment: @HenningMakholm's set $A$ is clearly still a Lebesgue measure null set (statistically, "all" numbers are normal). What would happen if one strengthen  that "local" measure requirement, and say that for each interval $(a,b)$ the intersection $A\cap (a,b)$ must possess a Lebesgue measure, and that measure is exactly half of the interval length, $(b-a)/2$? That seems hard to come up with. But why would it not exist?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Good question -- I've considered asking exactly that as a separate question (but didn't get around to it yet).

Comment: That is a very similar question to this one that I just recently found - http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2123343/everywhere-super-dense-subset-of-mathbbr/2123347

Comment: Edvin, nice reference. In that thread Robert Israel says no: a set that locally carries exactly half the "weight" of the real numbers in the sense of the latest comment above by myself and @HenningMakholm, does not exist.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let
$$\mathbb A=C+\mathbb Q=\{x+y:x\in C,\ y\in\mathbb Q\}$$
where $C$ is the Cantor set, and let $\mathbb B=\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb A.$

Since $\mathbb A$ and $\mathbb B$ are Borel sets ($F_\sigma$ and $G_\delta$ respectively), it will suffice to show that $\mathbb A\cap(a,b)$ and $\mathbb B\cap(a,b)$ are uncountable.

Since $\mathbb A$ has measure zero (as the union of countably many translates of $C$), $\mathbb B\cap(a,b)$ has positive measure, so it's uncountable.

Choose $q\in\mathbb Q\cap(a,b).$ Since every neighborhood of $0$ contains uncountably many points of $C,$ every neighborhood of $q$ contains uncountably many points of the set $C+q;$ in particular, the interval $(a,b)$ contains uncountably many points of the set $C+q\subseteq C+\mathbb Q=\mathbb A.$

Answer (score 5):

Consider the set
$$\big( (-\infty, 0) \cap \Bbb Q \big) \cup \big([0, \infty) \cap (\Bbb R - \Bbb Q) \big)$$
---that is, the union of the negative rationals and the nonnegative irrationals---and its complement.

Comment: I forgot an important nuance in the definition, but your example works for what I wrote at first

Answer (score 3):

**Yes:**

$$A= \{ x=b.b_1b_2..b_n... | 0.b_2b_4b_6... \in \mathbb Q \} \\
B= \{ x=b.b_1b_2..b_n... | 0.b_2b_4b_6... \notin \mathbb Q \} $$

For any interval $(a,b)$ it is easy to construct onto functions from $A \cap(a,b) , B \cap(a,b) $ to $(0,1)$.

Indeed, pick some $a < \frac{k}{10^{2n}} <  \frac{k+1}{10^{2n}} < b$ and show that 
$$ x=b.b_1b_2..b_n... \to 0.b_{2n+1}b_{2n+3}...$$
is onto function from $A \cap(a,b)$ and $B \cap(a,b) $ to $(0,1)$.

This example has the roots in the example of a discontinuous function with the IVP that appears in Sierpiński (I think).

Comment: What's this about an Initial Value Problem (IVP)??

Comment: @bof Intermediate Value Property